# Ternary operator returns 'undefined' instead of expected value

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Given a number, the function must return the negative of that number (it might already be negative). Why does the ternary operator not work in this case? Using an if statement works.

```
// Does not work
function makeNegative(num) {
  num < 0 ? num : -num;
}

// Works
function makeNegative(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    return num;
  }
  return -num;
}

// TEST
console.log(makeNegative(-4)); //-4
console.log(makeNegative(6)); //-6
```

Comment: You are missing the return statement. If you use the ES6 arrow function you can omit that `const makeNegative = (num) => num < 0 ? num : -num`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to `return` your value:

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
    return num < 0 ? num : -num;
}
```

If you want to use implicit returns, you need to convert your function to an arrow function:

```js
const makeNegative = num => num < 0 ? num : -num;
```

By the way, you can use negative `Math.abs()` for that purpose:

```js
const alwaysNegative = -Math.abs(num);
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes thank you. I usually use arrow functions, thought implicit returns would still work.

Comment: It was my first thought that you like implicit returns :)

Comment: You probably meant "arrow" function instead of "array". I tried to edit, but it's too short of a change for the system to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement in the ternary operator function. Try it like this:

```
function makeNegative(num) {
  return(num < 0 ? num : -num);
}
```

Comment: `return` is not a function, please avoid using confusing code style.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign `num`, you are missing the `=`:

```js
function makeNegative(num) {
  num = (num < 0) ? num : -num;
}
```

For more information, you can check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

EDIT: I looked at the question again, and given the usage in this case, this will not work. If you were looking to apply the method to the number without a return value, this would be the solution, but in this case, you would be looking for a `return` statement. I will keep my answer here as reference for others, but it is not the answer to @Awscr's question.

Comment: The suggested code does not change the behaviour of function `makeNegative()`.

Comment: It does change the behaviour simply by adding `num =` to the beginning. I do admit my answer was not what Awscr was looking for. @Robo Robok has added an implicit return method to his answer, what I was trying to demonstrate (albeit incorrectly). I will probably delete/revise this answer soon when I have time.